# Can you use map to create instances without a wrapper?

Tags: dictionary, swift

In Python, you can give the name of a class as an argument to `map` in order to create instances of that class:

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, (x, y)):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

coords = [(1., 2.), (3., 4.)]
pts = map(Point, coords)
```

This often proves to be a handy pattern, so I wanted to try the same thing in Swift.

---

First, we set up our `Point` class:

```
import Cocoa

class Point
{
    var x: Float
    var y: Float

    init(x: Float, y: Float) {
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    }
}

var pt = Point(x: 1, y: 2) // works fine
```

But when we try to use `.map` to create instances, we get an error:

```
let coords: (Float,Float)[] = [(1, 2), (3, 4)]

// (Point).Type is not convertible to '(Float, Float) -> $T3'
var pts = coords.map(Point)
// Initializer cannot be referenced without arguments
var pts = coords.map(Point.init)
```

What's interesting to me is that if we first define a wrapper function, this *does* work:

```
func wrapper(x: Float, y: Float) -> Point {
    return Point(x: x, y: y)
}

// This *is* successful
var ptsWrapped = coords.map(wrapper)
```

---

Ok, so now I'm curious whether this is a prohibition against using `map` on methods:

```
extension Point {
    func newPointByAdding(x: Float, y: Float) -> Point {
        return Point(x: self.x + x, y: self.y + y)
    }
}

// This works as expected
var origin = Point(x: 0, y: 0)
var ptsAdded = coords.map(origin.newPointByAdding)
```

...nope, that works fine.

---

I'll freely admit that I haven't yet spent much time with swift, so I may be missing something in the spec which prohibits this.

**Is it possible to use `map` to create new instances of a class/struct in swift?**

If not, why not?

- is it because `init` is not a `func`?
- is it something to do with named arguments not being convertible to positional arguments in certain contexts?

Answer (score 5):

#### Update for Swift 2:

Filing bugs works!

In Swift 2 this is now possible with `coords.map(Point.init)`:

[image]

---

Old answer:

> - is it because init is not a func?

Yep. In Swift, a [function type](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH31-XID_1007) "consists of a parameter and return type separated by an arrow (`->`)", and `map` is defined as `func map<U>(transform: (T) -> U) -> [U]`, i.e. it takes in a function. In [the grammar](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-XID_474), "function declaration" and "initializer declaration" are treated separately. The latter doesn't have a return type because it's not really a function, just a block of code used to initialize instances. And if you try to pass `Point.init`, you'll get the error "Initializer cannot be referenced without arguments".

[File a bug!](http://bugreport.apple.com)

Comment: Right... and changed as of Swift 2.0. See @Cenny's answer below or http://ericasadun.com/2015/06/25/swift-init-a-lovely-day/

Answer (score 2):

This is now possible in Xcode 7.0 beta 2

from the [release notes](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_7_beta_2/Xcode_7_beta_2_Release_Notes.pdf)

> Initializers can now be referenced like static methods by referring
> to .init on a static type reference or type object:
>
> ```
>   let x = String.init(5)
>   let stringType = String.self
>   let y = stringType.init(5)
>   let oneTwoThree = [1, 2, 3].map(String.init).reduce(“”, combine: +)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I think your conclusion is correct: `init` isn't being treated as a conventional func. You might want to report this as a bug; I'm not sure if this is intended behavior or not.

BTW, a more concise way to achieve what you want is:

```
coords.map{ p => Point(x: p[0], y: p[1]) }
```